# How could I segment a long Bezier cruve and add some control points to the path that I have found to make sure this curve never hit the obstacles?

Tags: python, algorithm, path-finding, bezier

I'm generating a grid 2D map with 50*50 size with `random` distribution to the obstacles. These obstacles have different heights according to my `drone_flight height = 60`.

I'm working on improving a trajectory for multirotor UAV and I need to get a continuous trajectory by using `Bezier curves`. It means I need to get one `Bezier curve`. I have applied the `Bezier python code` and `B-spline codes` that I have found here in the links below:

https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics/blob/master/PathPlanning/BSplinePath/bspline_path.py

https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics/blob/master/PathPlanning/BezierPath/bezier_path.py

and they work well, but the `Bezier curve` sometimes enters the `safe_zone` around the obstacles that I made. For me, I tested here both of them (`Bezier and B-spline`), but I need to work just with `Bezier curves`.

I'm planning to segment the long `Bezier curve` that I get to multiple segments until to add some control points to the segment of the curve that enters the `safe_zone` of obstacles to pull it out towards the path. I attached below a picture for my path with `B-spline` and `Bezier curve`. The Bezier curve with green color and how it entered the yellow safe_zone.

[image: PathPlanning]

Could I get assistance on how to `segment` the `Bezeir curve` and how to add control points to a specific segment?

P.S. My map is generated randomly and the obstacles have height are also random. So, at every running will be new values and shape.

Bezier Python Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.special

show_animation = True


def calc_4points_bezier_path(sx, sy, syaw, ex, ey, eyaw, offset):
    """
    Compute control points and path given start and end position.
    :param sx: (float) x-coordinate of the starting point
    :param sy: (float) y-coordinate of the starting point
    :param syaw: (float) yaw angle at start
    :param ex: (float) x-coordinate of the ending point
    :param ey: (float) y-coordinate of the ending point
    :param eyaw: (float) yaw angle at the end
    :param offset: (float)
    :return: (numpy array, numpy array)
    """
    dist = np.sqrt((sx - ex) ** 2 + (sy - ey) ** 2) / offset
    control_points = np.array(
        [[sx, sy],
         [sx + dist * np.cos(syaw), sy + dist * np.sin(syaw)],
         [ex - dist * np.cos(eyaw), ey - dist * np.sin(eyaw)],
         [ex, ey]])

    path = calc_bezier_path(control_points, n_points=100)

    return path, control_points


def calc_bezier_path(control_points, n_points=100):
    """
    Compute bezier path (trajectory) given control points.
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :param n_points: (int) number of points in the trajectory
    :return: (numpy array)
    """
    traj = []
    for t in np.linspace(0, 1, n_points):
        traj.append(bezier(t, control_points))

    return np.array(traj)


def bernstein_poly(n, i, t):
    """
    Bernstein polynom.
    :param n: (int) polynom degree
    :param i: (int)
    :param t: (float)
    :return: (float)
    """
    return scipy.special.comb(n, i) * t ** i * (1 - t) ** (n - i)


def bezier(t, control_points):
    """
    Return one point on the bezier curve.
    :param t: (float) number in [0, 1]
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :return: (numpy array) Coordinates of the point
    """
    n = len(control_points) - 1
    return np.sum([bernstein_poly(n, i, t) * control_points[i] for i in range(n + 1)], axis=0)


def bezier_derivatives_control_points(control_points, n_derivatives):
    """
    Compute control points of the successive derivatives of a given bezier curve.
    A derivative of a bezier curve is a bezier curve.
    See https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives
    for detailed explanations
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :param n_derivatives: (int)
    e.g., n_derivatives=2 -> compute control points for first and second derivatives
    :return: ([numpy array])
    """
    w = {0: control_points}
    for i in range(n_derivatives):
        n = len(w[i])
        w[i + 1] = np.array([(n - 1) * (w[i][j + 1] - w[i][j])
                             for j in range(n - 1)])
    return w


def curvature(dx, dy, ddx, ddy):
    """
    Compute curvature at one point given first and second derivatives.
    :param dx: (float) First derivative along x axis
    :param dy: (float)
    :param ddx: (float) Second derivative along x axis
    :param ddy: (float)
    :return: (float)
    """
    return (dx * ddy - dy * ddx) / (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** (3 / 2)


def plot_arrow(x, y, yaw, length=1.0, width=0.5, fc="r", ec="k"):  # pragma: no cover
    """Plot arrow."""
    if not isinstance(x, float):
        for (ix, iy, iyaw) in zip(x, y, yaw):
            plot_arrow(ix, iy, iyaw)
    else:
        plt.arrow(x, y, length * np.cos(yaw), length * np.sin(yaw),
                  fc=fc, ec=ec, head_width=width, head_length=width)
        plt.plot(x, y)


def main():
    """Plot an example bezier curve."""
    start_x = 10.0  # [m]
    start_y = 1.0  # [m]
    start_yaw = np.radians(180.0)  # [rad]

    end_x = -0.0  # [m]
    end_y = -3.0  # [m]
    end_yaw = np.radians(-45.0)  # [rad]
    offset = 3.0

    path, control_points = calc_4points_bezier_path(
        start_x, start_y, start_yaw, end_x, end_y, end_yaw, offset)

    # Note: alternatively, instead of specifying start and end position
    # you can directly define n control points and compute the path:
    # control_points = np.array([[5., 1.], [-2.78, 1.], [-11.5, -4.5], [-6., -8.]])
    # path = calc_bezier_path(control_points, n_points=100)

    # Display the tangent, normal and radius of cruvature at a given point
    t = 0.86  # Number in [0, 1]
    x_target, y_target = bezier(t, control_points)
    derivatives_cp = bezier_derivatives_control_points(control_points, 2)
    point = bezier(t, control_points)
    dt = bezier(t, derivatives_cp[1])
    ddt = bezier(t, derivatives_cp[2])
    # Radius of curvature
    radius = 1 / curvature(dt[0], dt[1], ddt[0], ddt[1])
    # Normalize derivative
    dt /= np.linalg.norm(dt, 2)
    tangent = np.array([point, point + dt])
    normal = np.array([point, point + [- dt[1], dt[0]]])
    curvature_center = point + np.array([- dt[1], dt[0]]) * radius
    circle = plt.Circle(tuple(curvature_center), radius,
                        color=(0, 0.8, 0.8), fill=False, linewidth=1)

    assert path.T[0][0] == start_x, "path is invalid"
    assert path.T[1][0] == start_y, "path is invalid"
    assert path.T[0][-1] == end_x, "path is invalid"
    assert path.T[1][-1] == end_y, "path is invalid"

    if show_animation:  # pragma: no cover
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(path.T[0], path.T[1], label="Bezier Path")
        ax.plot(control_points.T[0], control_points.T[1],
                '--o', label="Control Points")
        ax.plot(x_target, y_target)
        ax.plot(tangent[:, 0], tangent[:, 1], label="Tangent")
        ax.plot(normal[:, 0], normal[:, 1], label="Normal")
        ax.add_artist(circle)
        plot_arrow(start_x, start_y, start_yaw)
        plot_arrow(end_x, end_y, end_yaw)
        ax.legend()
        ax.axis("equal")
        ax.grid(True)
        plt.show()


def main2():
    """Show the effect of the offset."""
    start_x = 10.0  # [m]
    start_y = 1.0  # [m]
    start_yaw = np.radians(180.0)  # [rad]

    end_x = -0.0  # [m]
    end_y = -3.0  # [m]
    end_yaw = np.radians(-45.0)  # [rad]

    for offset in np.arange(1.0, 5.0, 1.0):
        path, control_points = calc_4points_bezier_path(
            start_x, start_y, start_yaw, end_x, end_y, end_yaw, offset)
        assert path.T[0][0] == start_x, "path is invalid"
        assert path.T[1][0] == start_y, "path is invalid"
        assert path.T[0][-1] == end_x, "path is invalid"
        assert path.T[1][-1] == end_y, "path is invalid"

        if show_animation:  # pragma: no cover
            plt.plot(path.T[0], path.T[1], label="Offset=" + str(offset))

    if show_animation:  # pragma: no cover
        plot_arrow(start_x, start_y, start_yaw)
        plot_arrow(end_x, end_y, end_yaw)
        plt.legend()
        plt.axis("equal")
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    #  main2()
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to use the spline (which looks good)? Or that the spline also sometimes passes through the safe zone?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I don't need to use B-spline. I need to use the Bezier curves. For B-spline, I just tested it.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Concatenating Bezier curves such that they are continuous (you probably want C2 or C3 continuity) is quite hard and virtually impossible. That's what splines are for.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I know that dear about B-spline works very well and it is common, but according to my thesis work, my professor insisted to work with Bezier curve.

Comment: Could you then please add some requirements? I.e. will you have one Bezier curve or multiple? Is their degree variable? What continuity do you want? How exactly do you want to segment? Do you want to add any control points or are there requirements? To me, all of this sounds like an entire research question which cannot be answered in the short SO format. See also [help/on-topic].

Comment: @NicoSchertler I will try to rephrase my post.

Comment: the control points you show suggest you don't want "a bezier curve" but a polybezier consisting of cubic Beziers. If so: just build that, then find out which curve(s) intersect the safe boundary, find the `t` value(s) on those curves where the intersections occur, and then split those curves at their intersection `t` value (which is [fairly easy](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#splitting)).